# how to invoke sshfs within python script?

Tags: python, sshfs

I want to mount a remote directory using sshfs. sshfs working fine from terminal.
But how to invoke it from within python script?

I tried something like this - but didn't work at all.

```
import os

cmd = "/usr/bin/sshfs giis@giis.co.in:/home/giis /mnt" 
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: And what was the result? We can help you better if you tell us what went wrong.

Comment: here is the output : 

python: can't open file 'sshfs': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Is the path correct? try `which sshfs` to find out in shell.

Comment: sshfs is in the correct path. Manually invoking sshfs mounts the remote-directory under local mount point. but don't about using python script ...

Comment: yes..got it sshfs installed with root permission and changing to root and executing above script worked :) ..thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, you should make sure your sshfs command works fine using the shell. Then, go to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=subprocess+Python) to see many examples of using subprocess module of Python to call your sshfs commmand

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
mount_command = f'sshfs {host_username}@{host_ip}:{host_data_directory} {local_data_directory}'
subprocess.call(mount_command, shell=True)
# Do your stuff with mounted folder
unmount_command = f'fusermount -u  {local_data_directory}'
subprocess.call(unmount_command, shell=True)
```